# How to convert â€“ to - in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, character-encoding

Help me to fix this problem. The page should display `-` instead of `â€“`.

I already have `<meta charset="utf-8" />` on my html `<head>`, I'm using visual studio code set to `UTF-8`, and the database. I'm using is mySQL, the version of my laravel is 5.4.

The `â€“` comes from the database and i'm not allowed to alter it.

Comment: check your mysql database and table charset, is that utf8 or latin, if you are running migration through laravel by default charset is utf8mb4 and collection utf8mb4_unicode_ci

Comment: the table and database are latin1_swedish_ci, they are not from laravel migration, it was from other web application. should i change the config/database.php to match it with latin?

Comment: what language you are trying to save. english or other.

Comment: I'm try to save english

Answer (score 0):

I got tired from debugging and decided to fix it using javascript

```
window.onload = function() {
     removeFunnyCharacters();
}


function removeFunnyCharacters() {
     var titles, arrTitles;
     titles = document.querySelectorAll('.c-project__title');
     arrTitles = Array.prototype.slice.call(titles);

     arrTitles.forEach(function(cur) {
         cur.innerHTML = cur.innerHTML.replace('â€“', '-');
     });
}
```

Comment: You do know that that’s a terrible and inadequate solution, right?

Comment: No, please please provide clean and better solution.

Comment: That’s impossible to say without more details at this point. See the duplicate and http://kunststube.net/frontback for hints.